# How to get previous data with RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I use a hook in a standard way:

```js
const { data, isLoading } = useGetSomeDataQuery()
```

Data is an array of items with `id`.

I use polling so data updates periodically.

Items can be removed from the array on the backend side as they are not relevant anymore.

Once a single item has gone and new data has been fetched without it, I'd like to show a notification like "An item with ID 1234567890 was processed and removed from the queue".

To do this I need to have access to previous data, before it was fetched and put inside `data` object.

I don't see a clear solution that is provided out of the box by RTK Query, so my solution is to put `data` into local state via calling `useState()`, and then compare it every time new data is coming from `useGetSomeDataQuery()`.

What are better, may be more RTK-friendly options?

Comment: Caching the current result in local component state is one way that will work. You could cache it elsewhere if you like, i.e. like in the Redux store you are already using. It depends on how transient the previous result is and what/where it needs to be known, e.g. if it's worth the extra effort to store in global state, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a different state to get previous data. You have to manage two state in redux Slice like

```
const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: {
    currentData: null,
    previousData: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.previousData = state.currentData;
      state.currentData = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

From this you can get previous data from redux.